# Automatically enabling bash completion on Fedora 28

Tags: bash, fedora

I have a Fedora 28 installation on which I have installed the bash bash-completion package.

I have run the following:

```
source /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
```

And bash completion works as expected.

However, whenever I re-login, I must run the above command before bash completion starts working - it is not enabled automatically.

I have checked the permissions of the `bash_completion.sh` file and even added the `x` flag, but it is still not enabled automatically.

How can I get this working?

Comment: You can add this command in .bashrc file. I know it is just a workaround, but it will work until you investigate real rootcause.

Comment: StackOverflow's focus is *software development*. Environment configuration is a better fit for [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/etc/bashrc` file provided by the `setup` package, will source all scripts in `/etc/profile.d/` by default. Also, by default your `~/.bashrc`, should have the following (you can verify it's the default by looking in `/etc/skel/.bashrc`) :

```
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

Here's the relevant part (towards the end) of that file that I see on my system (Fedora 28 Workstation):

```
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        if [ "$PS1" ]; then
            . "$i"
        else
            . "$i" >/dev/null
        fi
    fi
done
```

Here's the version of `setup` that I'm using (and proof that that's where it comes from):

```
$ rpm -q --whatprovides /etc/bashrc 
setup-2.11.4-1.fc28.noarch
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. My `/etc/bashrc` file does not contain this. However a similar loop is in my `/etc/profile` file. Is your file standard, or have you customised it? My RPM version of setup is `setup-2.11.4-1.fc28.noarch`, and I ran `rpm -V setup` which shows that my files have not been modified

Comment: @DanielScott hmm, that's interesting. I was just going to ask you to run `rpm -V setup` because I can see from running it that my `/etc/bashrc` isn't modified from the rpm. Can you check to see if you've got an `/etc/bashrc.rpmnew` file, and if so, what the differences between the two are?

Comment: Nope, no `/etc/bashrc.rpmnew` file. Also, if I run `bash -l` then I get a new login shell and the completion works correctly!

Comment: That's bizarre that the files are different between our machines. I clearly don't understand `rpm -V` enough.

Comment: I just downloaded the source from http://releases.pagure.org/setup/setup-2.11.4.tar.bz2 - my files are identical to these. I just found them here too: https://pagure.io/setup/tree/master

Comment: @DanielScott I think our files _are_ identical then, since I see the lines from my answer there, starting at https://pagure.io/setup/blob/master/f/bashrc#_83 (if you've got that, then I think your bash_completion.sh should get loaded, unless for some reason that file is ignored)

Comment: @DanielScott I think I found the discrepancy: in my `~/.bashrc`, I've got the following: `
    # Source global definitions
    if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bashrc
    fi`
Do you have that? Edit: argh, can't newline in a comment. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178697/discussion-between-gerard-ryan-and-daniel-scott).

Comment: Sorry, I've been on holiday - the entry in my ~/.bashrc seems to have fixed it!